# Apply to Static Class Variable to Xaml Attribute

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

How do you refer/use a static class variable as a XAML attribute value?

For example; AppConstants.cs

```
public class AppConstants {
    public static readonly Color TextColor = Color.FromHex("aaaaaa");
}
```

HomePage.xaml (the below code is invalid)

```
....
<Button TextColor="AppConstants.TextColor"/>
....
```

What is the correct syntax to 'reference' `AppConstants.TextColor` inside the attribute `TextColor`?

Answer (score 3):

Try the [x:Static Markup Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Generic code:

```
<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" .../>
```

Specific example:

```
<Button TextColor="{x:Static AppConstants.TextColor}"/>
```

Comment: What is the need for ```<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" .../>``` is a little confusing.

Comment: The `<object .../>` is just a generic example, the next line is the specific example for 'Button' object